# Oracle SQL Recursive Query

Tags: oracle, recursion, recursive-query

Have a query regarding this - have a table update where I have to backfill for over a years worth of data, and due to the code I have to update by day (which takes 4-5 mins per day), does anyone know how I can do this more effectively by setting a list of dates so I can do this in the background.

So for example if I set a variable called :reqdate which is the date field and I have a list of dates from a query (e.g. 01/01/20, 02/01/20... 04/04/20) is there something I can do to get sql to run this repeatedly eg :regdate=01/01/20, then when thats done it automatically does 02/01/20 and so on

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example of what you want ?

Comment: so something like with datelist as (select * from dates) insert into tablename select * from tableview where date=:reqdate on a loop

Comment: try to make our life easier. Put an example of your input, and the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the easiest way is to use `merge` clause like:

```sql
merge into dest_table t
using (
   select date'2020-01-01'+N as dt 
   from xmltable('0 to 10' columns N int path '.')
) dates
on (t.date_col = dates.dt)
whem matched then update
   set ...
```

Though I think you need to redesign your update to simple update like

```sql
update (select ... from) t 
set ... 
where t.dt between date'2020-01-01' and date'2020-01-20'
```